# Writes [object Object] to csv file using fast-csv

Tags: node.js, csv

I´m using `fast-csv` to export some data from a DB to a CSV file.

When I use the code from the example in the [docs](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) :

```
        var csvStream = csv.createWriteStream({headers:true}),
        writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('./csv/list.csv');

        writableStream.on('finish', function(){
            console.log('DONE!');
        });

        csvStream.pipe(writableStream);
        csvStream.write(
            [
                {
                    a: "a1",
                    b: "b1",
                    c: "c1"
                }
            ]
        );
        csvStream.end();

        res.send('export done!')
```

my csv file have one entry `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `csvStream.write()` will only accept object arguments:

```
csvStream.write({
  a: "a1",
  b: "b1",
  c: "c1"
});
```

If you want to write arrays, you should use `csv.write()` or `csv.writeToStream()` (documented [here](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv), search for *"Writing data"* as I can't link to it directly).